# How to use use `with(user(` when using Spring Session/Security in REST environment

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-session

Is it possible to pouplate a Test User with `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user` when using Spring Session with `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy`.

I tried something like:

```
mockMvc.perform(
    get(URL)
        .with(user("user").password("pwd").roles("USER", "ADMIN")))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
```

But it returns a 403.
Without the `with(user(` I get the a 401 so there is a difference.

I've a faily simple `SecurityConfig` containing:

```
    http
        .anonymous()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("USER")
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new NullRequestCache());
```

I's very similar like https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/1.0.1.RELEASE/samples/rest as I have an endpoint with I authenticate to with http basic. It returns the authentication token via the header which is then used in other REST calls.

So I was hoping that I just could use the `with(user(` in this scenario to make my tests easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should be able to do this. The problem is that

```
.with(user("user").password("pwd").roles("USER", "ADMIN")))
```

is applying roles which means the ROLE_ prefix is automatically added.

In contrast, your configuration is using:

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("USER")
```

which does not automatically add the ROLE_ prefix. Instead, try using:

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
```

NOTE: I have also updated the tests to include an [example of with(user("user"))](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/e4c74ebe91a0d8c4d421575d2350c56b4f937d8a/samples/rest/src/integration-test/java/rest/RestMockMvcTests.java#L82).

Comment: Thanks Rob, this indeed was the issue.